# Two proper subsets of the real numbers, $A$ and $B$, that have the following conditions: $A$ and $B$ are closed, $A \cap B$ is empty, +1

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to show that there can exists two proper subsets of the real numbers, $A$ and $B$, that have the following conditions:

(1) $A$ and $B$ are closed (with respect to the usual metric)

(2) $A \cap B$ is empty.

(3) inf$\{d(a,b): a \in A, b \in B \} = 0$

Obviously, for just the first condition $A = [0,1] = B$ would work.

Add in the second, and we can have A = $[0,1]$ and $B = [2,3]$

Now the third condition is where this problem gets me. I'm not sure how to apply $inf = 0$ for disjoint subsets in this context.

Can anyone think of an example for this?

Edit: To clarify, I'm trying to find an example that satisfies all three conditions

Comment: The question seems to me to be asking you for a single pair of sets satisfying all three conditions. You seem to be trying to find three different pairs, each satisfying one.

Comment: I was trying to break down my approach to the question in steps so I don't get bogged down in the details of trying to explain everything in one go.

Comment: Gotcha. You may want to clarify that in the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was tricky! The idea, is you can't think of the sets as intervals. As there are not two intervals for which this is true.

Consider $A = \{2,3,4,5, \ldots\}$. This is a closed set. Consider $B =\{2+1/2, 3+1/3, 4+1/4, 5+1/5, \ldots\}$. This is also a closed set.

Now, $A$ and $B$ are clearly disjoint and for $n \ge 2$, we have that $n \in A$ and $n + 1/n \in B$. Thus the distance between these points is $1/n$. This is true for all integers $n \ge 2$ and hence they have distance $0$ between the sets.

Answer (score 3):

$(X, d) $ be a metric space.

$A$ and $B$ be two subsets of $X$.

1. $A\cap B =\emptyset$
2. $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed.

(1) and ( 2) implies $d(A, B) >0 $.
(The proof is not difficult at all)

So, to find two closed disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ such that $d(A, B) =0$ , you  have to consider both sets to be non-compact . Otherwise it is not possible.  Think about it.